# Причастные оборот, стоящий посередине двойного дополнения

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Выберите, списав текст, правильную каждого слова форму из предложенных в тексте, написанном ниже, взятого из песни(,) исполненной Михаилом Боярским(,) «Долгий путь».